# How can i make common componet for antd Menu?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

i want to make antd menu common component from that i will import antd menu in my Menu.js component and whenver i want to use antd menu i will import my menu.js component instead of antd menu but in this structure i got one error

here is my menu.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Menu as AntMenu } from 'antd';



const Menu = ({items, ...extraAttributes }) => {
  return (
    <AntMenu
      items={items}
      {...extraAttributes}
    />
  );
}
export default Menu;
```

but now how can i use menu.Item , menu.SubMenu , and Menu.ItemGroup because i didnt exported or returned in my component how can i write menu.js that makes my componet same as like ant i mean
menu.Item , menu.SubMenu , and Menu.ItemGroup  can be used by importing from my Menu.js component

i tried exporting

```
import { Menu as AntMenu } from 'antd';
const { SubMenu, Item, ItemGroup } = AntMenu;

export { Menu, SubMenu, ItemGroup, Item };
```

still it not working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign them to your Menu

```js
const Menu = ({items, ...extraAttributes }) => {
  return (
    <AntMenu
      items={items}
      {...extraAttributes}
    />
  );
}

const { SubMenu, Item, ItemGroup } = AntMenu;

Menu.SubMenu = SubMenu
Menu.ItemGroup = ItemGroup
Menu.Item = Item

export default Menu
```

Now you can

```js
import Menu from "path/to/my/menu"

function Comp() {
  return (
    <Menu>
      <Menu.Item>Item</Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
  )
}
```

Comment: it is working for Menu.Item and Menu.Submenu but Menu.ItemGroup is not working because it is function in antd , I get to know from doing console of Antd Menu , that's why this errors comes , is there any solutions

Comment: Working fine after some adjustment